# Recommendation for tracking device

Tags: gps, heart-rate, performance-tracking

I plan to buy a tracking watch/device and I'm looking for recommendations. Two key features that I can think of are

- heart rate monitor
- gps tracking

I think that Polar M400 provides these features, but I was hoping to get some educated advice.

Comment: Certainly most of the Garmin computers provide these. At the low end, you need to check whether the devices support HRMs.

Comment: What is HRM? Can you link?

Comment: Heart Rate Monitor

Comment: Seems like the M400 has it, right?

Comment: There are several manufacturers that make these devices: Garmin, Suunto, Polar, TomTom, FitBit, etc... One good website for reviews is http://www.dcrainmaker.com/.

Comment: @DrorAtariah I have no idea without checking. I'm not familiar with that computer. But there's nothing to stop _you_ checking.

Comment: I use the strava.com  app with both HRM sensor and Cadence sensor (when its working) and it works great.   We have a strava club for SE Bicycles too.

Comment: Please clarify what is your objective. Polar M400 is just smartwatch(that battery need to be recharge after 8 hours  ) come with GPS, you need to purchase Polar H7 sensor for heart rate monitor.

Comment: M400 HR comes bundled with the belt. I haven't seen the non-HR version sold anywhere, probably because without the belt the watch is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Garmin Forerunner 235 which has these features. The heart rate monitor is built into the back of the watch, rather than using a chest strap which I think the Polar model does.

It can also connect to bike speed/cadence sensors, your smart phone etc.

A dedicated bike computer like the Garmin Edge 810 is also useful as it adds a map display and route planning.

Comment: I had the Fitbit Charge HR which also measures heart rate using a LED sensor at its back. This was supper inaccurate. Actually, I think I'd prefer to put a strap and get accurate measurements.

Comment: A lot of smartwatches will also measure your heart rate, but only a few will support gps tracking

Comment: I checked the HR monitor agaisnt another device at rewults were  close. Some discussion of accuracy here http://www.wareable.com/garmin/garmin-forerunner-235-review Most of the people I run and cycle  with seems to favour Garmin, though Suunto seems to get a faster GPS fix.

Comment: Compared to Suunto, Garmin puts far more effort to sponsoring and marketing. I guess that shows.

Comment: @DrorAtariah Garmin has it's own sensor, it seems fine for me - much more accurate then a cheap Sigma with a strap

Answer (score 0):

We don't do specific product recommendations.

However I got a cheap $25 ANT+ HRM off DX.com and it has work superlatively for the last 6 months, on the original battery.

I got a cheap cadence meter off a local supplier and its been nothing but rubbish.  Chews through a battery in a day or two, and is very hard to find.  I'm glad it was on clearance at $20 down from $80, cos I wouldn't have been happy with its performance at $80.

Many modern android phones have ANT+ built in.  No Apple product has ANT+ - they all depend on BLE Bluetooth Low Energy.

IMO Cheaper items win out because of their replaceability.  Expensive ones smash just like cheap ones, why waste the money on pricey sensors?

This advice doesn't apply to power meters- I don't own one and cannot comment.  There are no "cheap" power meters.

Comment: Regarding "expensive ones smash just like cheap ones": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyHDPkPerHA. The ad is overdramatized, but the dropping, freezing, etc tests are real.